# while calling java method in jsp page, it is showing servlet.service exception nosuchmethod

Tags: java, jsp

I am calling java method in jsp page that is showing servlet.service exception nosuch method exception or class

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="Model.Validation"%>
<%
String username=request.getParameter("uname");
String password=request.getParameter("password");
System.out.print(username+"\nhellloo\n"+password+"\n re\n");
ArrayList<String> names=Validation.validateuname(username,password);
String name=(String)names.get(0);
String role=(String)names.get(1);
 if(role.equals("Administrator"))
 {
out.print("{success:true,errors:{reason:'Administrator'},uname:{name:'"+name+"'}}");

}else if(role.equals("User"))
 {
out.print("{success:true,errors:{reason:'User'}}");

}else
 {
 out.print("{success:false,errors:{reason:'User name or Password is wrong, please try              again'}}");

  }

%>
```

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Model.Validation.validateuname(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/ArrayList;
>       at org.apache.jsp.check_005flogin_jsp._jspService(check_005flogin_jsp.java:61)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 1):

The StackTrace is telling you that there is no method

```
public class Validation {
    public static ArrayList<String> validateuname(String, String) {
        ArrayList<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();
        //a nice implementation goes here!
        return ls; 
    }
}
```

Check if this is a valid method. If your method is right, then recompile your code and deploy your web application again.

---

There is a major problem in your code, you must not use scriptlets (the Java code inside the `<% ... %>` inside your jsps). There is a further explanation about the problems and solutions for this:

- [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/1065197)

Comment: I have declared the method and it is working if i am running java class

Comment: @YarramReddy post your `Validation#validateuname` method to check any errors.

Answer (score 0):

the exception is being throw here on this line

```
ArrayList<String> names=Validation.validateuname(username,password);
```

is Validation a reference ?, if it is a reference to an  object check your validatename()method in that class. from your code i can say its not a reference you are trying to call valudatename() with the class name. 
try this:

```
  ArrayList<String> names=new Validation().validateuname(username,password);
```

Comment: @YarramReddy can u post your model class.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that your method `validateuname` exists in your Validation class.
2. Make sure that you have compiled the class, saved it to proper project directory in your server (Seems that you are using **Tomcat**), and that you have restarted the server. Note that in every new method declaration, you need to restart your server.